# 1 Hot Receptacle 2 Light Fixtures 1 Switch - Is it possible?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just barely finished re-wiring my bathroom on a circuit that connects to the hall light. So currently is is composed of the hall 1)light/switch 2)bathroom light/switch 3) bathroom receptacle. I would like to add another light fixture above the vanity in the bathroom because the overhead light casts a shadow.

Here is a diagram of the current setup:
[image: bathroom wiring]

Is it possible for me to add another light fixture off of the switch in the bathroom? And if so what would I need to do?

Comment: Shouldn't be hard.  The black-white bus running along the right and bottom look to be always-hot, you can just branch off of that.

Comment: Do you have another circuit servicing this bathroom already?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have the hot receptacle on a circuit between the hall light and bathroom light.

Comment: @aguertin -- that doesn't answer the question I asked -- by Code, each bathroom needs to have at least one of its receptacles on a dedicated 20A circuit...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, I wasn't sure what you meant. I actually had to look up what 20A was. The answer is yes, it does have 20a dedicated with 14ga wire

Comment: @aguertin -- what? 20A circuits require 12ga wire...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel apparently they are 12g actually, I guessed wrong. I took a pair of wair cutters with the gauge sizes on them and they are in fact 12g solid copper

Comment: @aguertin -- cool -- just didn't want you to get into a Code pickle here.

Answer (score 2):

According to your diagram, yes it is possible.

You would connect it similar to your existing bathroom switch.  Run a #14/2 ROMEX (or other appropriate cable) to the light fixture.  The white wire would tie into the white wire on your diagram. The black would connect to one terminal of your switch, and you would connect the other terminal of the switch to the black wire in your diagram (the one on the bottom).  Bond the ground wire to the other grounds in the box or the ground screw.

Alternatively, you could power the new light from the existing switch.  With a 2 wire cable, connect the white to white.  Connect the black of the new wire to the red existing wire along with a pigtail (a 6" or so short wire).  Connect the pigtail to the top terminal of the switch.  This will allow one switch to turn both lights on at the same time.

Comment: I will try this out and of it works I will mark as answer